# Detect whether there is a way out of a 3D room

Tags: java, algorithm, maze

I'm developing this for *Bukkit*, but I am open to porting a java-only solution.

Now, I have a character in a room with an opening exposed to the outside for radiation to seep in like this:

[image: dead_man]

(sorry for terrible paint skills)  In this picture the algorithm should return false, however if that white bit was covered, it would return true.
I need a way of detecting whether the character is inside a room or not. Please remember that a room can be any size, and does not have to be a cuboid.

The way I'd like it to work is that I'd have an arbitrary position above the roof, and if this maze algorithm would be able to reach this position, I'd know that the character is not completely covered.

EDIT: Actually if the exit was 20+ units away, I wouldn't mind the algorithm timing out.

Comment: What do you consider to be a room?

Comment: @Campbell A closed structure which does not have an opening to the sky.

Comment: Does it have to have walls? if so, how many? Does it have to have a flat floor? Can the ceiling only be a certain height?

Comment: Your question is very broad. For example, how is your room-data even stored/structured? Do you already have some kind of code? Then please show it to us. I mean do you have some kind of collision polygon for the room? What exactly do you have and how is it structured?

Comment: Minecraft (the intended platform) is a sandbox game, these rooms are not stored in memory, the user would be able to build any kind of structure, hence the need for a complex algorithm.  All structures are built with blocks; these blocks may be arranged in ANY pattern, even a sphere like this: http://www.plotz.co.uk/_gfx/minecraft-sphere-generator-1.jpg. I just need to know whether there is any opening to the sky.

Comment: then a simple flood fill would do

Comment: @Sopel How would I go about that?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer per se, but it may be a good point to move on from.

1. The definition for room:

> a part or division of a building enclosed by walls, floor, and
>   ceiling.

2. The definition for building:

> a structure with a roof and walls

3. The definition of a structure:

> a building or other object constructed from several parts

Can you see how poorly defined these are? (The definitions for building and structure are recursive!) Until you can come up with a clear cut, black and white definition for what you consider to be a room, you (and us) have very little hope of coming up with a good solution.

Comment: The room I describe is merely an area which is completely enclosed by other blocks.

Comment: In your picture there is an opening.

Comment: I meant that the algorithm should return true since there is an exit, sorry that wasn't clear, I'll edit the post.